# How to manipulate AngularJS scope properties with external JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have a table (html) filled with some data which is provided with AngularJS. Now I would like to change a particular property of each entry within the scope. How can I access and manipulate a specific property of a tuple in a scope?

I tried as shown in JavaScript code below. It all worked well until the alert pops up. The code below the alert `$scope.selects.day = 'Superhero';` didn't work. What's the problem here?

HTML table:

```
<select name="manipulate" onchange="change()">
    <option value"doSomething">Do Something</option>
    <option value"doSomethingElse">Do Something else</option>
</select>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="select in selects | filter:model">
            <td>{{select.day}}</td>
            <td>{{select.subcategory}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Angular JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters']);
myApp.controller('controller', function($scope) {

var content = [ 
    {subcategory: 'XYZ',day: 'Monday',},
    {subcategory: 'ABC',day: 'Tuesday',},
];

$scope.selects = content
});
```

Java Script:

```
function change() {
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=myApp]');
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();

    $scope.$apply(function() {

    //alert('Works until here')
    $scope.selects.day = 'Superhero';

    });
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you please elaborate the `didn't work` part.

Comment: @vs1682 there is no error. Just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is very wrong and you should not do that for any reason. If you want to add additional js files go with `import` and `export`, here's some documentation, it's big so I won't cover that part but there are tons of answers here (stackoverflow) on the subject:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

To fix your code, first you have a typo on option fields they are missing `value=`:

```
<option value="doSomething">Do Something</option>
<option value="doSomethingElse">Do Something else</option>
```

Second, I have no clue what filter: model does so I will just delete that part and you need to use angularjs ng-change instead of javascript onchange:

```
<select name="manipulate" ng-model="someModel" ng-change="change()">
```

Create change function that will loop through all properties of the selects on $scope and change value of 'day' property.

```
function change() {
  $scope.selects = $scope.selects.map(val => {
    val.day = "Superhero"
    return val;
  });
}
```

And at the end put change function and selects on the $scope:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
  selects: content,
  change,
})
```

Also there's no need to manually trigger digest cycle because angularjs will do that for you so try to avoid it.

Everything's here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/r6Ly8j8L/1/

Comment: is val.day iterating? What I means is, is it possible to do some calculation there which is different for each increment depending on its value?

Comment: you can and if you need index .map((val, index) => { ....somecode.... return val;})